# frida calls the wrong constructor

Tags: java, android, frida

I'm trying to hook the following constructor of java.net.URL:
URL(URL context, String spec, URLStreamHandler handler)

My code is as follows:

```
import argparse
import frida
import sys

jscode = """
Java.perform(function () {
    Java.use('java.net.URL').$init.overload('java.net.URL', 'java.lang.String', 'java.net.URLStreamHandler').implementation = function(arg0,arg1,arg2) {
          return this.$init(arg0,arg1,arg2);
      };
});
"""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("target")
args = parser.parse_args()
process = frida.get_usb_device().attach(args.target)
script = process.create_script(jscode)
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

This causes the application (and sometimes frida-server) to crash. Inspecting the logcat shows:

```
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:391)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:316)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:339)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(Native Method)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
03-25 16:09:03.347 23490 23563 E AndroidRuntime:        at okhttp3.HttpUrl.url(HttpUrl.kt:1)
...
```

This means that the init I tried to call is the wrong init function, as the URL.java:339 maps to the `URL(String protocol, String host, String file)` constructor. I suspect this might be because both arg0 and arg2 are null in this call chain.

Is there a way to call to a specific overload?

Comment: Have you tried something like `return this.$init.overload('java.net.URL', 'java.lang.String', 'java.net.URLStreamHandler').call(arg0, arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't call the constructor. A later call to the url.toString() fails because `this` is null. Adding a console.log after (without the return) doesn't print the message. I'm using frida 12.8.15 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on the [frida github](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/1227).
The solution is:

```
Java.perform(function () {
  var URL = Java.use('java.net.URL');

  var ctor = URL.$init.overload('java.net.URL', 'java.lang.String', 'java.net.URLStreamHandler');
  ctor.implementation = function (arg0, arg1, arg2) {
    return ctor.call(this, arg0, arg1, arg2);
  };
});
```