# Frida - Calling a specific method overload

Tags: javascript, java, android, security, frida

I am exploring an Android program that has several methods with the same names and parameters.

I need to call a specific method overload.
Java code like this

```
package a;
public class d
{
     public int a() {
        return 10;
    }

    public long a() {
        return 20;
    }
    public long b() {
        long ret = a();
        return ret + 1;
    }
}
```

I need replace implementation of b() and call (int)a() instead of (long)a(). 
Please help me fix my frida js code.

```
Java.perform(function () {
  Var Class_A_D = java.Use("a.d");
  Class_A_D.b.implementation = function(){
    var ret = this.(a); // need to call int implementation
    return ret;
 }
}
```

Comment: For the special case of a constructor this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880361/150978 For a regular method this should also work the same way.

Comment: It is not my case. "overload" construction select funtion by types of input parameters. But both of my methods without parameters . Мethods differ in return parameters.

Comment: OK; the code is heavily obfuscated and even violates the basic principle of overloaded methods of Java (didn't know that this is possible). Hence I only see the way to get a list of all methods and then filter them for the name, the parameters and the return type until only one method remains. This one method you can then call as shown in the answer linked in my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with Java.reflect

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var Java_lang_Object = Java.use('java.lang.Object');
    var Java_lang_String = Java.use('java.lang.String');
//This function get method reference by reflect
        function dynamic_search_method(io_object, iv_name, iv_ret_type, it_par){ 
          var lt_methods = io_object.getMethods()  ;
          var lv_found;
          for(var  lv_i=0;lv_i < lt_methods.length;lv_i++){
             if(lt_methods[lv_i].getName().toString()  == iv_name && lt_methods[lv_i].getGenericReturnType().toString() == iv_ret_type){
                var lt_par_type = lt_methods[lv_i].getParameterTypes();
                if(lt_par_type.length == it_par.length){
                  lv_found = true; 
                  for(var  lv_j=0;lv_j < lt_par_type.length && lv_found == true;lv_j++){
                    if(lt_par_type[lv_j].getName().toString() != it_par[lv_j]) lv_found = false  ; 
                  }                   
                  if(lv_found == true) return lt_methods[lv_i];
                }
             }
          }
         return null;
        }
//This function call method dynamically 
        function dynamic_invoke(io_object,io_method, it_par){
          if(io_object===null || io_method ===null ) return null;
          try{
            var lo_cast_obj = Java.cast( io_object ,Java_lang_Object);
          }catch(e){
            return null;
          }
          var lt_par = Java.array('java.lang.Object',it_par);
          return io_method.invoke(lo_cast_obj,lt_par);
        }
//example of use
  Var Class_A_D = java.Use("a.d");


  Class_A_D.b.implementation = function(){
// call method "a" of instance, with "long" return and without parameter
var lo_meth = dynamic_search_method(this.getClass(),"a","long",[]);
var lv_var= dynamic_invoke(this,lo_meth,[]);

// call method "c" of instance, with "android.content.Context" return and with 2 parameters
lo_meth = dynamic_search_method(this.getClass(),"a","class android.content.Context",['java.lang.String','java.lang.String']);
var lv_var= dynamic_invoke(this,lo_meth,[Java_lang_String.$new("Test"),Java_lang_String.$new("String")]);
// call static method
var lo_meth = dynamic_search_method(Class_A_D.class,"d","class java.lang.String",[]);
var lv_var= dynamic_invoke(Class_A_D.class,lo_meth,[]);    
};

)};
```

Answer (score -1):

The code in class d is violating the method signature principle which is defined by the method name and each parameter type.

Because the method type is not part of the signature Java reads these methods as the same:
  public int a() {...}
  public long a(){...}

both signatures are "a()"

You should rename those methods to have different names ( or to have input parameters of different types )

More info here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Of course, I can’t rename the method in a "foreign" APK file (full decompilation into smali, changing the name and rebuilding apk is too time consuming)